# Django admin incorrect behaviour

Tags: javascript, django, frontend

We are using Django 1.11 as backend and managing tool for mobile application resources. One of my coleagues (on OS: Windows 7) recently started to have problems like:

- cannot add new one2many items in `inlines` (missing `+` sign)
- cannot lookup new item from `raw_id_fields` - this instead of popup window redirects to url in the same tab and shows blank page
- when clicked on "check all" box, only this very box is checked, not the rest of the records as expected

I tried on my computer with the same (super)user, everything worked just fine. It seemed that he may have problems with javascript so we've tried run simple alert from js console and it worked. Turning off the antivirus did not help either. As this happens in all browsers it is clear that it is a problem of the computer, not django itself. But it worked a month ago so I would like to know what might be the cause and how to get rid of this behaviour.

Comment: if you open the developer tools in the browser, do you see any errors? seems definitely like a problem with running javascript.

Comment: @dirkgroten you are right, he just reported me that all javascripts from AWS S3 storage failed to be loaded. Do you have any idea why it happens?

Comment: Difficult to say what it could be. If you can ask him to copy the link to one of these js files directly in the browser address bar to see the response/error. It could be a DNS issue since it’s happening in all browsers.

Comment: the scripts do not show, the browser says there is no connection, the message is similar whether using https (secure connection failed) or http (connection failed) and asks us to try again later. Just to be sure I checked if the IP address is blocked by any chance, but it is not. We both see the content of the bucket - it's a mess if displayed via browser, but at least I can expect that DNS is OK as url correctly resolves to the same IP

Comment: Not sure I understand. When typing the full URL to the javascript, the browser says connection failed, but when using the IP address of the bucket, it shows something. Did you try the full path to the javascript file with IP address as hostname instead of bucket.s3.amazonaws.com?

Comment: Yes, I tried it, but amazon complains that `The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint.`

Comment: I would try to open up a terminal in Windows and check a few things, like dns resolution (using `dig`) and trying to download the file using `curl`/`wget`. Except I'm not familiar with Windows so I'm not sure of the equivalent for these.